# HTML Hyperlink not working dreamweaver

Tags: html

I basically have a navigation bar on the top with 6 hyperlinks and I have coded for each of them. However the hyperlink doesnt work properly. Upon further research I found that the hyperlink will be active only when clicked in a certain location. Usually top-middle of text. Here is the code I'm using. Thanks in advance for your help.

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url();
  border-bottom: thin solid;
  font-size: large;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 0px;
  ;
  border-bottom: thin solid #FFFFFF;
  font-size: large;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}

#nav_wrapper {
  height: 66px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha (opacity=70);
  border-bottom: thin inset #000000;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "SamsungSharpSansRegular Regular";
}

#nav_wrapper ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}

#nav_wrapper a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#nav_wrapper ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transition: all 0.45s;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"><br>
  <div id="nav_wrapper"><br>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="REALIndexPage.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="AboutUS.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="Devs.html">Developers</a></li>
      <li><a href="About5G.html">S9 | S9+</a></li>
      <li><a href="Forum.html">Forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="Developments.html">Recent</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Likey a CSS issue. You are covering something or narrowing something. Please post a [mcve]  with relevant CSS using the `<>` stacksnippet editor. Also why <br/>? Use padding

Comment: sorry im not sure how to use the stacksnippet editor but i displayed the css above THNX!!

Comment: Given code is working fine, you can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/349yam1x/)

Comment: Im lost whats fiddle?

Comment: Just click the [<>] button in the editor. I did it for you. Now you can click "edit this snippet" if you need

Comment: JSFiddle.net is a site where one can make the same executable code as in a stacksnippet - click on his link to see

Comment: Your code works - there must be something else on the page  - for example something "position:absolute" that is interfering. You can find out by right clicking a menu and choose "inspect" that will show you if the link is covered by something

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/349yam1x/embed/"></script>

Comment: I cant seem to find anything though. I tried inspect in dreamweaver and google chrome but still same bug appears

Comment: Inspect will not fix the bug - it will highlight what might be overlying your links.

Comment: the only thing thats on top of it is the div#nav

Comment: Unless we can reproduce the problem, we can't really help you. Please see [mcve]